# Why is my integration test failing for get? "ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

Why is this test giving this error?

#### Error

```
  1) Error:
PostIntegrationTest#test_should_not_show_comment_box_if_not_logged_in:
ArgumentError: bad argument (expected URI object or URI string)
    test/integration/post_integration_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:PostIntegrationTest>'
```

#### Code, post_integration_test.rb

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostIntegrationTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  test "should not show comment box if not logged in" do
    get :show, 'id' => 1                       ########### LINE 6
    assert_select 'textarea', false, "Comment textarea must not exist if not logged in"
  end
```

#### Also doesn't work

```
get :show, {'id' => 1}
get :show, {id: 1}
```

#### Reference

This says you can pass arguments. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/TestCase/Behavior.html#method-i-get

This is an example of using parameters to `get`: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#setup-and-teardown

#### Version

```
$ rails -v
Rails 4.0.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`:show` is not available in Integration tests, the actions are only available in Controller tests.  You need to either use `_path` helper or string representation of your url.

```
test "should not show comment box if not logged in" do
  # Assuming path is /posts.  Replace accordingly.
  get "/posts/1"                      ########### LINE 6
  assert_select 'textarea', false, "Comment textarea must not exist if not logged in"
end
```

Comment: Wow that worked. I could have sworn it was working before but thought I broke something in the non-test code or gem related.

Answer (score 4):

From the examples given in [Rails Testing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html) we see that, in **Integration Tests** get/post/put/delete has a url as first argument. While **Controllers Tests** has the name of action.

Its because in controller test **minitest** knows that of which controller's actions(show, destroy, new, create) is being called, because we specified the that **Controller Name** in our test class name. And so  in **Integration Tests** we must pass the url.